# Do I need more PHP memory space?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

Hi :) I have only very basic knowledge in homepage coding. (also I'm Austrian, sorry for bad English)

Somehow after the WordPress update the footer and the right sidebar are gone and I checked the footer.php in WordPress and compared it to another code and there is this line in my footer.php:

```
<?php wp_footer(): ?>
```

and the ":" should be a ";", if I'm not wrong. When I try to change it and save it, I get an error message that says that the PHP changes weren't saved because of an error in the wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php file, line 466. Here is the code in that file from line 465 to 470:

```
if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
    $script = "$data\n$script";
}
return $this->add_data( $handle, 'data', $script );
}
```

That error message is new, before the update there was no such error message. So I don't know if I should delete that or not, and before I screw up everything, I kindly ask the experts of stack overflow :D

I also get a second message and it says "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20963856 bytes)". And I did some research and according to some pages it means, that PHP has not enough space? I don't know if I should contact the hoster, where the page is hosted but the contract is about unlimited space. Or is PHP space something different? Sorry for so many questions.

I tried researching but I am too scared of messing up the base code of WordPress by deleting something, that's why I ask professionals here.

I tried to Google the space problem and I am not sure what it means and if I should contact the hoster about it.

Comment: _"I get an error message that says that the php changes weren't saved"_ - Are you editing that file through Wordpress admin?

Comment: yes, I edit it in wordpress over Design -> Theme Editor -> footer.php

Comment: It sounds like you need to contact Wordpress support. SO is for when you're having _programming_ issues with _your code_. This is basically a product support question.

Comment: okay, thank you a lot for your help, I'll contact them.